# Doctrine ORM cache errors after removing entity property

Tags: php, caching, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I've removed the column/property `id` from my `Entity` and I think there are some caching problems that causes the following errors when trying to access the `Entity`:

```
Uncaught ReflectionException: Given object is not an instance of the class this property was declared in in [...]/vendor/doctrine/persistence/src/Persistence/Reflection/TypedNoDefaultReflectionPropertyBase.php:33
Stack trace:
#0 .../vendor/doctrine/persistence/src/Persistence/Reflection/TypedNoDefaultReflectionPropertyBase.php(33): ReflectionProperty->isInitialized(Object(Project\Entities\Entity))
#1 .../vendor/doctrine/orm/src/UnitOfWork.php(586): Doctrine\Persistence\Reflection\TypedNoDefaultReflectionProperty->getValue(Object(Project\Entities\Entity))
...
```

```
Creation of dynamic property Project\Entities\Entity::$id is deprecated;
.../vendor/doctrine/persistence/src/Persistence/Reflection/RuntimeReflectionProperty.php; 60
```

I've run `php config/cli-config.php orm:generate-proxies` (successfully generated new proxies), but when tried any from the following to clear cache:

1. `php config/cli-config.php orm:clear-cache:query`
2. `php config/cli-config.php orm:clear-cache:metadata`
3. `php config/cli-config.php orm:clear-cache:result`

I get such error:

```
In MemcachedAdapter.php line 300:
                                                     
  MemcachedAdapter client error: connection failure
```

The 'hotfix' is to change the `isDevMode` param to `true` here:

```
return new EntityManager(
    DriverManager::getConnection($params),
    ORMSetup::createAttributeMetadataConfiguration(
        paths: [__DIR__ . '/../Entities'],
        isDevMode: true, // :(
        proxyDir: __DIR__ . '/../../../tmp',
    ),
);
```

Please help me properly fix these errors. I have no idea what to do/check next.

Running on:

1. PHP 8.2
2. Doctrine ORM 3.1.0
3. Doctrine DBAL 4.0.1
4. Symfony cache 7.0.4

`cli-config.php` is basically:

```
ConsoleRunner::run(new SingleManagerProvider($entity_manager));
```

**To clarify:**

I've changed this:

```
#[Id]
#[Column(name: 'id', type: Types::INTEGER, updatable: false, options: ['unsigned' => true])]
#[GeneratedValue]
private int $id;
```

to this:

```
#[Id]
#[OneToOne(targetEntity: Base::class, inversedBy: 'entity')]
#[JoinColumn(name: 'id', referencedColumnName: 'id', unique: true)]
private Base $base;
```

and `SHOW CREATE TABLE entity;` gives:

```
CREATE TABLE `entity` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `entity_base_fk` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `entity_base_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `base` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci
```

Comment: Have you run migrations in order to update your db etc? Or if you aren't using migrations, you should drop and recreate the schema and repopulate it using fixtures (or a data only db dump,  but that would need editing as your id column would still be in it)

Comment: i see you use symfony, try a `console doctrine:migrations:diff`, and then run that migration

Comment: @delboy1978uk it's only Symfony cache which is required for standalone doctrine unfortunately

Comment: @delboy1978uk I've added small clarification at the end of my post

Comment: your db does need updating,  youve changed an auto incrementing primary key into a foreign key to another table. run `console doctrine:migrations:diff` followed by `console doctrine:migrations:migrate`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot clear APCu Cache from Console, it's shared in the Webserver memory and not accessible from the CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78178979/cannot-clear-apcu-cache-from-console-its-shared-in-the-webserver-memory-and-no)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it's because of `apcu cache` which

> is only accessible to the webserver.

and in `php.ini` `apc` was disabled for CLI explaining why `orm:clear-cache` defaulted to `MemcachedAdapter`

```
apc.enable_cli=0
```

enabling it doesn't help as they are different caches for webserver and CLI, so I needed to trigger `apcu_clear_cache()` in a webserver using e.g. `curl` to a specific (secured) script