# Cannot clear APCu Cache from Console, it's shared in the Webserver memory and not accessible from the CLI

Tags: php, caching, doctrine, memcached, apcu

I'm trying to clear doctrine cache after updating entities, so that there won't be errors like this after adding new property:

```
Uncaught Error: Typed property Project\Entities\Entity::$property must not be accessed before initialization in ...
```

`php cli-config.php orm:clear-cache:metadata` and `php cli-config.php orm:clear-cache:result` works fine but when I'm trying to execute `php cli-config.php orm:clear-cache:query` I get Error:

```
In QueryCommand.php line 43:
                                                                                                              
  Cannot clear APCu Cache from Console, it's shared in the Webserver memory and not accessible from the CLI.
```

If I disable APCu for CLI in php.ini like this:

```
apc.enable_cli=0
```

then `orm:clear-cache:query` results in:

```
In MemcachedAdapter.php line 300:
                                                     
  MemcachedAdapter client error: connection failure
```

as Doctrine defaults to MemcachedAdapter if APCu is unavailable.

When creating `EntityManager` with `isDevMode` set to true, it works fine (no errors occur) but I'm not convinced it's a valid solution.

```
new EntityManager(
    DriverManager::getConnection($params),
    ORMSetup::createAttributeMetadataConfiguration(
        paths: [__DIR__ . '/../Entities'],
        isDevMode: true, // should be false as it's production
        proxyDir: __DIR__ . '/../../../tmp',
    ),
);
```

Versions:

1. PHP: 8.2
2. Doctrine ORM: 3.1
3. Doctrine DBAL: 4.0

I'm not using Symfony, just plain Doctrine.

How to approach this issue so that I could correctly clear the production cache?

Comment: The first error message is not cache related. You simply access a property before it was set.

Comment: @Markus Zeller actually it is, forgot to add that when creating EntityManager with isDevMode: true (so that it will use ArrayAdapter as cache) it works fine

Comment: If it is just the webservers cache, why not just restarting it? With apache2 you can do a graceful restart, so no request is killed. `service apache2 graceful`. This will only restart the web service not the whole system.

Comment: @MarkusZeller as I'm not the owner of the server I don't have permissions to manage services
service apache2 graceful
.: cannot open /etc/rc.subr: Permission denied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, [Doctrine's official documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/3.1/reference/caching.html) states that :

> None of these tasks will work with APC, APCu, or XCache drivers
> because the memory that the cache is stored in is only accessible to
> the webserver.

You can then act directly on the webserver **using PHP commands in a webpage** (not through CLI).

Here's the code I personally use:

```
$doctrine = orm_instance();
    
echo "getResultCache() CLEAR <br>";
$cacheDriver = $doctrine->em->getConfiguration()->getResultCache();
$cacheDriver->clear();
                
echo "getQueryCache() CLEAR <br>";
$cacheDriver = $doctrine->em->getConfiguration()->getQueryCache();
$cacheDriver->clear();
                
echo "getMetadataCache() CLEAR <br>";
$cacheDriver = $doctrine->em->getConfiguration()->getMetadataCache();
$cacheDriver->clear();

dump($doctrine->em);
```

Another simple way is to execute the [APCu](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apcu-clear-cache.php) native methods in a PHP webpage too.

```
$result = apcu_clear_cache();
dump(apcu_cache_info());
```

Comment: Do you hide or secure it somehow? I want to clear cache during deployment and I wonder if there is any better solution than creating e.g. api endpoint with password parameter, so that noone would be able to clear cache at any time.

Comment: Secured via user’s credentials/roles. If you want to do it quick (and a bit dirty), you can configure a secure folder via .htaccess file if you are running your code on Apache.